# find-replace across a whole table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have multiple SQL tables , each with several columns where, due to bad php code, values that should be NULL are 0.

I want to change all the 0s to NULLs in all columns and all rows.

Is there any way that I can quickly find all values that are 0 (irrespective of the column or row they are in) in a table and update them to NULL?

I want to do it with SQL code in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Would it really be so hard to write an `UPDATE` statement which explicitly mentions the columns?  I don't think there is a very nice way to literally do what you are asking.

Comment: There are many tables and the column names are each unique.

Answer (score 2):

I cant think of any easier way to do this

```
update yourtable
Set col1 = case when col1 = 0 then NULL else col1 end,
    col2 = case when col2 = 0 then NULL else col2 end,
    ....
Where 0 in(col1,col2,..)
```

You have to do this to all your tables. If `Mysql` supports dynamic Sql then you can use it to frame the update queries with the help of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS` Table

Comment: And I couldn't agree more +1

Comment: For dynamic sqls +1